# Making threads in static constructors

Tags: c#, multithreading, static-constructor

In the following example code it appears that the thread that's made in the static constructor only ever gets run after the static constructor finishes executing. In this case that results in the static constructor never finishing because of the wait.

What's going on here?

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

static public class Test
{
    static public bool isDone = false;

    static Test()
    {
        Thread a = new Thread(TestThread);
        a.Priority = ThreadPriority.Highest;
        a.Start();

        while (!isDone)
            Thread.Sleep(1);

        Console.WriteLine(isDone);
    }

    static private void TestThread()
    {
        isDone = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Try making the constructor Public.

Comment: That works, but it doesn't answer the question and it leads to more elaborate code for what I want to do.

Comment: The code without Public is using a built-in constructor and not your constructor.  So it is not executing your code.

Comment: @jdweng That's not true. Static constructor is run the first time and member of the static class is accessed.

Comment: Not to mention that static constructors can't have access modifiers.

Comment: Then why does Public work?

Comment: It doesn't. A static constructor can't be public. I've tried this, even though it makes no sense because you can't call a static constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**: I was writing non-sense.  Static constructors execute under a lock to prevent multiple threads from initializing the static class more than once.  However, you try to access your class from multiple threads before this initialization completes, therefore your code results in a deadlock.
See explanation [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2011/05/03/static-constructor-deadlocks/)

Comment: That still doesn't cause the thread to run during the constructor strangely enough.

Comment: Indeed, and I found the reason why and edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: Now it makes sense, thanks.